# Is the following true ? about n number of normal subgroups of G

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that we have the following subgroups of G, in which all of them are normal denote them by $P_1,...,P_n$.

Is the following true

$P_1....P_n$ is a subgroup of G, and $|P_1...P_n| = \frac{|P_1|...|P_n|}{|P_1 \cap P_2 .... \cap P_n|}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I formulate a lemma which I suppose you know well

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $H,K$ be subgroups. Then:
>
> 1. $|HK|= \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$
> 2. If $H$ is normal, then $HK$ is a subgroup
> 3. If $K$ is normal, then $HK$ is a subgroup

So, arguing by induction it is easily seen that $P_1 \cdots P_n$ is a subgroup. The problem is that the cardinality of $P_1P_2P_3$ is
$$|P_1P_2P_3|= \frac{|P_1P_2||P_3|}{|P_1P_2 \cap P_3|} = \frac{|P_1||P_2||P_3|}{|P_1 \cap P_2||P_1P_2 \cap P_3|}$$

So, if your formula were true, you would have
$$|P_1 \cap P_2||P_1P_2 \cap P_3|=|P_1 \cap P_2 \cap P_3|$$
which is false in general, since $P_1 \cap P_2 \cap P_3 \subseteq P_1 \cap P_2$

Comment: what is the general formula for $|P_1 ... P_n|$ ?

Comment: how did you get $|P_1P_2 \cap P_3| = |P_1 \cap P_2| |P_1P_2 \cap P_3|$ also is it true that if all the $P_i$ are disjoint is it true that we get $|P_1 .. P_n| = |P_1| |P_2| .... |P_n|$?

Comment: I don't think that a general formula for $|P_1 \cdots P_n|$ exists. As for your second question, if you assume that your formula is valid, then you have $$\frac{|P_1||P_2||P_3|}{|P_1 \cap P_2 \cap P_3|} = \frac{|P_1||P_2||P_3|}/{|P_1 P_2 \cap P_3||P_1 \cap P_2|}$$ now, simply compare denominators. For disjoint $P_i$s I think that nothing could be said.